# Logging options for Slick

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm createing a Play 2.1 app, in which I have decided to use Slick for database interaction.
However I can't find documentation about how to configure/enable logging for Slick.
Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 17):

For PlayFramework 2.5.0 without Slick

Add to all your database configurations

```
db.default.logSql=true
```

Add to your logback.xml file:

```
<logger name="logger.org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger"  level="INFO" />
```

All the statements will be logged.

## Reference:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#How-to-configure-SQL-log-statement

For play with Slick 3.0, just use

```
<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"  level="DEBUG" />
```

Comment: But `play-slick` uses these paths for the config `slick.dbs.default.xxx`, so where should I put it?

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps. I believe Play-Slick is not integrated with jdbcdslog but you can get the queries directly from Slick.

Comment: Thank you very much! Interestingly (and that's why I was confused) in the "What's New in Play 2.5" it says `Play now has an easy way to log SQL statements, built on jdbcdslog , that works across all JDBC databases, connection pool implementations and persistence frameworks (Anorm, Ebean, JPA, Slick, etc).` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Highlights25#logging-sql-statements)

Comment: I could be wrong but reading the play framework code I can't see Slick integrated with jdbcdslog. For sure it does not read the config for logSql. Maybe an issue should be opened.

Answer (score 16):

Slick doesn't do much of any logging above `DEBUG` level.  In `application.conf` if you add the line:

> `logger.scala.slick=DEBUG`

you're going to get deluged with information from the query compiler.

You're probably just interested in the session information (Connection pool management, query strings, etc).  In which case, just add

> `logger.scala.slick.session=DEBUG`

to your Play application's `application.conf`

Comment: With logger.scala.slick.session=DEBUG it only shows select statements but no updates, deletes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in all cases, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087858/turn-slick-logging-off (which worked in my case) what may be the reason?

Comment: Please note that in Slick 3.* the logger name should be `logger.slick` and `logger.slick.session`

Answer (score 12):

To print only select statements, in play-2.2.1 with slick 2.0.0, in application.conf have:

```
logger.scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not using Play at the moment, but configure it as you would use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). [This is a nice description](https://github.com/royguo/Play2.0-CN-doc/wiki/SettingsLogger) for setting up Play logging.

One option is to add

```
logger.scala.slick=INFO
```

to application.conf, as per Play manual. The other, if you have a custom logback.xml, is to add there the following line:

```
   <logger name="scala.slick" level="INFO" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Slick seems to use [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/) for its logging. So you might want to add a dependency on something like `slf4j-simple` to your project and set the desired log level for the Slick classes.

Comment: And that would mean, for a working example, adding the slf4j-simple-[1.7.5].jar into classpath and -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=trace to the command line.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried to integrate the *logback.xml* with the Slick logger but it doesn't work.

Modifing *logger.xml* (get it the latest version from GitHub based on your version) and adding the slick logger, instead, works.

```
<configuration>    
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

  <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourself -->
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="scala.slick" level="SQL" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: With Slick 3.1.0 (via Play Framework) I found I needed to use `<logger name="slick" level="SQL" />`

Answer (score 1):

For slick 3.1.0, paste this in `logback.xml` in your `resources` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="slick" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ah, I guess it's because I'm using logback and you're using something else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add `<logger name="slick" level="INFO"/>` to my `log4j2.xml` file. I'm using Slick 3.0.3 with Spray 1.3.3 and Log4j 2.1