# Silence slick logging

Tags: scala, logging, slick, slick-3.0

When I run our test suite slick decides to log at debug level, which makes it hard to see our test output and causes the suite to take longer. I can't figure out how to silence it. I've tried using slf4j-nop as suggested in slick's manual, but it seems our project uses several other loggers and slick is making use of one of those. Here's the relevant part of our project definition:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % SparkVersion,
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1101-jdbc41",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.1.1"
  ),
  dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % Slf4jVersion,
    "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % Slf4jVersion,
    "org.slf4j" % "jul-to-slf4j" % Slf4jVersion
  ),
  dependencyOverrides in test := Set(
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"), //no-op logger for slick
```

Some of the things I've tried already, none of which work:

- add  `logback.xml` to the test resources as suggested in [Turn Slick logging off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087858/turn-slick-logging-off).
- add `logging.properties` and `commons-logging.properties` to test resources with `.level=WARN`
- add `logger.scala.slick=WARN` in my `application.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick was using Log4j to do its logging. Strangely enough, just adding an empty `src/test/resources/log4j.properties` file to the project was good enough to silence it during test runs.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your `logback.xml`:

`<logger name="slick" level="WARN" />`

Comment: I edited the name in the logback.xml I'd tried from a suggestion in another question (from "scala.slick" to "slick" as you suggest), but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Also, the project didn't have an existing logback.xml to add to, nor is logback listed as a dependency, so I think we just aren't using it.