# Play! 2.5: deactivate slick logs

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, slick

I have a lot of slick logs at the start of the app and and after as the following:

```
[INFO ] p.PlaceMethods:  >>> binding uuid -> java.util.UUID  
[INFO ] p.PlaceMethods:  >>> binding text -> java.lang.String  
[INFO ] p.PlaceMethods:  >>> binding bool -> Boolean
```

I tried a lot of thing to deactivate them but without success (I have followed this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087858/turn-slick-logging-off) and some others but without results).

I'm using `Play! 2.5.10` with `play-slick 2.0.2`.

Here is what I have done:

in `logback.xml`:

```
<logger name="slick" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="scala.slick" level="ERROR" />
<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"  level="ERROR" />
<logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="ERROR"/>
```

and in `application.conf`:

```
logger="OFF"
logger.scala.slick="OFF"
logger.scala.slick.session="OFF"
logger.scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement="OFF"
logger.scala.slick.jdbc="OFF"
```

What am I missing to get rid of these logs?

Comment: How do you know they are from slick?

Comment: I guessed it because every classes injecting DatabaseConfigProvider have these logs printed and I don't have logs from the others. It could be false but I don't see where it could come from otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think, that `PlaceMethods` is a custom class from your project. You need to find its full path and add to the logger, like:

```
<logger name=".....PlaceMethods"  level="ERROR" />
```

**UPDATE**

You can operate on the package level as well.

Switch on `ERROR` level on the three classes in the package `crawler`

```
<logger name="crawler.Scratch" level="ERROR" />
<logger name="crawler.Bite" level="ERROR" />
<logger name="crawler.BiteWorker" level="ERROR" />
```

Switch on `ERROR` level for all classes in the package `crawler`:

```
<logger name="crawler" level="ERROR" />
```

Comment: Yes it is a custom class from my project but I don't want to deactivate all the logs for each classes injecting DatabaseConfigProvider... There are a lot and I don't want to have to add every new class into my logback.xml file

Comment: you can operate logs level on the package level, look at my update

Comment: Indeed but I want to keep the INFO level  for the rest of the logger since I use them. I just want to remove these particular info logs

Comment: so you need to set the INFO level for the "rest" and the ERROR level for these particular class.

Comment: I want INFO level for these particular classes as well. I just want that these Slick logs disappear