# Slick logging with slf4j-simple

Tags: scala, slf4j, slick, slick-2.0

I am using `slf4j-simple` in my project. I would like to change logging level for `slick` to INFO. After reading [Logging options for Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453447/logging-options-for-slick) 
and [Class SimpleLogger docs](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html)I have tried to add following options to my VM line:

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=INFO
-Dlogger.scala.slick=INFO
-Dlogger.scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement=INFO
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.scala.slick=INFO
```

I see a few INFO level logs comming from jetty, therefore the basic logging seems to be working. I am also able to change level of logs shown by using `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=TRACE`, but even that only shows more jetty logs, no Slick logs are shown to me.

How can I configure `slf4j-simple` to shown slick logs to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html the correct system property should be

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.scala.slick=debug
```

instead of

```
-Dlogger.scala.slick=INFO
```

For reference, the list of all loggers used by Slick can be found in [logback.xml](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/codegen/resources/logback.xml). We only use the `debug` level with all of them.