# How to print Slick query tree?

Tags: slick

I'm writing some code with Slick and I'd like to be able to print the "Slick Query Tree" - is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to see the abstract syntax tree for queries?! You can watch this movie: http://youtu.be/THlvR9bXHIc - it is also referenced at "http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/" below "Screencast 1: Introduction to the query compiler".

AFAIK you can use method `toNode` and `nodeChildren` in your own slick code to recursively traverse the AST.

Answer (score 2):

We log them.
See [Slick logging with slf4j-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870226/slick-logging-with-slf4j-simple)
See the available loggers here https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/common-test-resources/logback.xml

You'll need to look at the compiler ones.