# Scala, play - cannot insert into Postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a simple scala and play code for inserting product into database.

My database config in application.conf looks like:

```
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shop"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="root"
```

Table definition and crud operations:

```
case class Product(id: Long, name: String, description: String, price: BigDecimal, amount: Int)

case class ProductFormData(name: String, description: String, price: BigDecimal, amount: Int)

object ProductForm {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "description" -> nonEmptyText,
      "price" -> bigDecimal,
      "amount" -> number
    )(ProductFormData.apply)(ProductFormData.unapply)
  )
}

class ProductTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[Product](tag, "product") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def description = column[String]("description")

  def price = column[BigDecimal]("price")

  def amount = column[Int]("amount")

  override def * =
    (id, name, description, price, amount) <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)
}

object Products {

  val products = TableQuery[ProductTableDef]

  private def db: Database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

  def add(product: Product): Future[Int] = {
    try db.run(products += product)
    finally db.close
  }

  def delete(id: Long): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(products.filter(_.id === id).delete)
  }

  def get(id: Long): Future[Option[Product]] = {
    db.run(products.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
  }

  def listAll: Future[Seq[Product]] = {
    db.run(products.result)
  }
}
```

service:

```
object ProductService {
  def addProduct(product: Product): Future[Int] = {
    Products.add(product)
  }
}
```

and controller:

```
def create() = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val name = (request.body \ "name").as[String]
    val description = (request.body \ "description").as[String]
    val price = (request.body \ "price").as[BigDecimal]
    val amount = (request.body \ "amount").as[Int]

    val product = Product(0, name, description, price, amount)
    ProductService.addProduct(product)

    Ok("name : " + product.name)
  }
```

Everything looks good, no errors in process (I use postman, creating json and send it to server). But after all there is no data in databse. Even table is not created in database. I really don't know why this cannot be add to database.

**EDIT:**

```
create table "Product" ("id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"name" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"description" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"price" Decimal, "amount" BIGINT NOT NULL);
```

This is a script which I use to create table manually, then I try to save data frm request into database. From request everything is read fine (object Product is created) but no data still is safe into database.

**EDIT 2:**

```
case class Product(id: Option[Long], name: String, description: String, price: BigDecimal, amount: Int)

class ProductTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[Product](tag, "product") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def description = column[String]("description")

  def price = column[BigDecimal]("price")

  def amount = column[Int]("amount")

  override def * =
    (id.?, name, description, price, amount) <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)
}
```

I updated models and dao with Option auto increment field, but It didn't help.

Comment: Have you read up on how Evolutions work with Play? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions

Comment: Yes, but my code is created with some tutorials where evolutions were not used. Can you explain what should I add instead of alone "evolutions" into build.sbt to trigger queries?

Comment: In your question you stated "Even table is not created in database.". Without Evolutions the table won't be created for you. You need to manually create the table in your postgres db using a SQL statement. Make sure it corresponds to your ProductTableDef.

Comment: I created manually table "Product" in database but still not data is add there.

Comment: if you need a tutorial on play+slick have a look at this tutorial I wrote (for play2.4.x) a couple of months ago: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/
the code is available at Github: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/tree/step3 and there's even a play2.5.x branch: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/tree/play2.5 hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play action in controller asynchronous by default. So rendering finished before call to database finished. Call to database is a slow operation and this is condisidered as side effect: network + IO operation.
Simple way to check this is to put next code before rendering:

```
 Thread.sleep(2000)
```

What you actually should do is something like:

```
def add = Action.async( parse.json(userReads) ) { request =>
    val results = userRepo.insert(  UserData( None, request.body.name, request.body.note ) )
    results.map(_ => Ok("done") )
```

For creating required tables you should use something like:

```
val setup = DBIO.seq(
  // Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys
  (suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create,


  //
)

val setupFuture = db.run(setup)
```

Here is slick api documentation: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#schema

Not sure there you will place this logic in you webApp

Try to see SQL generated by Slick:

Update you method accordingly
 def add(product: Product): Future[Int] = {
    val action = products += product

```
   val sql = action.result.statements.toString()

   // this is SQL query which slick will try run against postGreed 
   // you should be able to run it manually from SQL console to see reason why this failing 
   println(sql)

db.run( action )
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but did you create a table manually or something? It works for you when you added Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Why you are expecting table to be created? Where logic for this ?? This should be done by other logic if you have some or manually. I would suggest flyway migration: https://flywaydb.org/ works good for me and simple to use as project evolves.

Comment: I do not expect. I think it should be automatically created after I trigger insert function.

Comment: Yes, you can create schema in Slick: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#schema , will update my answer

Comment: If you look at my code from first post, you can see I created everything, but data is not saved into database. I should add Thread.sleep() before `Ok("name : " + product.name)`?

Comment: Please make sure you have table with required structure in the db and there is no connection exception etc and then yes, try add Thread.sleep() before Ok(...) I did have this problem in the past, its quite painful to identify it ...

Comment: I created table `Product` in database, but it still not work. I do not get any data there.

Comment: its sounds strange .. but try then 2 things (temporary: ) val product = Product(0, name, description, price, amount) put some data manualy and in  def add(product: Product): Future[Int] = {
    try db.run(products += product)
    finally db.close
  } remove try/finally .. otherwise I am not sure what is the reason .. :((

Comment: I edited my first post. It still not works, even with this temporary solution. Moreover, I do not see anything in logs when I trying insert into database.

Comment: Well, downgrade this logic to console application, just to see if slick works fine for main part of logic, that the way I was learning slick

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, change autoIncr field to be Optional: something like: case class UserData(id : Option[Int], name: String, desc: String) In your case case class Product(id: Optional[Long], ...

Comment: I change field to be optional, but it didn't help... I cannot downgrade it to console application. I totally do not understand why this data is not saved intop db.

Comment: Well, there is an option to see SQL generated by Slick: could be printed to terminal this way:    val sql = query.result.statements.toString()
      println(sql) I will update my answer for you examples

Comment: I have done it and get result: Product(Some(3),some name,Jsome desc,45.00,1) - this is insert statement

Comment: Well, something very strange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453447/logging-options-for-slick

Comment: Finally it works! I changed my addProduct function (look first post) and now everything looks fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please update you question OR post new answer to close this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally it works. I changed my add function into:

```
 def add(product: Product): Unit = {
    try {
      Await.result(db.run(DBIO.seq(
        products.schema.create,
        products += (product),
        products.result.map(println))), Duration.Inf)
    } finally db.close
  }
```

and now schema is created and data is added into database.

Comment: just general advise to be careful with Await.result , but as long as it works, its good! More reading about Await.results: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html