# Single quotes cause trouble while filtering in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, h2, slick

I have statements such as below

```
  def create(company: Company): Future[Company] = {
    dbConfig.db.run(companies.filter(_.name === company.name).result.headOption)
}
```

and they fail with exceptions such as this

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement
```

I have tried to escape the single quote but wasn't successful.

```
dbConfig.db.run(companies.filter(_.name === company.name.replace("'", "''")).result.headOption)
```

When I tried to insert a record such as this:

```
val company = doSync(companies.create(Company(0, "C's company")))
```

The exception I've gotten is:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "select `id`, `name` from `company` where `name` = 'C\'s company[*]'"; SQL statement:
select `id`, `name` from `company` where `name` = 'C\'s company' [42000-200]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select `id`, `name` from `company` where `name` = 'C\'s company[*]'"; SQL statement:
select `id`, `name` from `company` where `name` = 'C\'s company' [42000-200]
```

Please note that I am using H2 in Mysql mode to run my tests.

Comment: 'I have tried to escape the single quote but wasn't successful' - could you post what you tried? Also you can log compiled query, please, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846676/3298917

Comment: Sure, I'll rephrase the question

Comment: Try escape it with an additional `single quote` (instead of `backslash`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error suggests to me that you have the wrong Slick profile imported. I'm not familiar with H2 in Mysql mode. Perhaps you need to use the MySQL profile? (Or the H2 one if you're using MySQL)

Comment: I'm already using the mysqlProfile in the code, I've double checked that.

Comment: I'd maybe try the H2 profile to see if that resolves the SQL syntax issues (with unmodified queries, that is). I don't believe you should need to change anything about the Slick query to make it run against a supported database.

Comment: It could try that but then it'd mess up with my production DB (MySql). That's why I run H2 in MySQL mode locally.

Comment: You can abstract out the profile, and mix in the right one locally vs. production to solve that difference. There's a section on that in Essential Slick: https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#abstracting-over-databases

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I struggle to understand how it can work in my setup: I have repository classes that do operations on the DB level, does it mean I need to use that trait in those classes?

Comment: I made it work eventually and it solved the problem (importing the JbdcProfile and letting the runtime import the correct profile eventually), but I still don't get why it solves the issue :S

Comment: It solves the issue because: different databases have differences in syntax and capabilities. The Slick profile defines how Slick generates SQL. So you have to import a correct matching profile for the database otherwise you'll get SQL issues. To use the same code on different database products, you need to abstract over the profile (e.g., via that example in Essential Slick). Great you have it working!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer indeed, but still I don't get it :) Because I've always imported MysqlProfile and yet it failed in my production instance which is Mysql, I didn't import anything else than Mysql